# Why can't I find this string in RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, jupyter

```
lines = []
total_check = 0

with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            print(line)
```

output data:

```
Totaalbedrag excl. btw € 25,00
```

When I try to retrieve VAT from data:

```
KVK_re = re.compile(r'(excl. btw .+)')
KVK_re.search(data).group(0)
```

output: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

```
KVK_re = re.compile(r'(excl. btw .+)')
KVK_re.search(r'excl. btw € 25,00').group(0)
```

output: 'excl. btw € 25,00'

How is it possible that when I paste the literal output in a search it does find the number € 25,00  and when I enter the data variable it does not?

Please help me!

Comment: Try `KVK_re = re.compile(r'(excl\.\s+btw\s.+)')`

Comment: Didn't work. I'll attach the output file for your reference

Comment: Then use `\W` to match any non-word char, `r'(excl\.\W+btw\W.+)')`

Comment: Thank you man! It worked. You're a legend

Comment: ```r = re.compile(r'[\w\s]+?(?<=\s)(.+)')```

Comment: This is a very valuable resource for regular expression needs: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, when a literal space is used in the pattern and there is no match, the reason is the invisible characters, or non-breaking spaces.

When you have non-breaking spaces, `\xA0`, you can simply replace the literal spaces with `\s` to match any whitespace, or `[ \xA0]` to match either of the spaces.

It appears there may be a combination of both spaces and some invisible chars in this case, thus, you may use `\W` to match any non-word chars instead of a literal space:

```
r'excl\.\W+btw\W.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide what the contents of the `data` object are, but the error message is just saying that the regex is not found. So you're probably calling search on data that doesn't contain that specific string.

```py
$ KVK_re = re.compile(r'(excl. btw .+)')
$ KVK_re.search('test').group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```